# unable to understand the base pointer calculation in assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, stack, x86-64

I am trying to understand the assembly code for the following function by doing a disassembler. I am unable to get why all the operations are relative to the base pointer.

1. Why are the register values of `rcx` and `rdx` moved to memory location offset by 10 and 18?
   ( `mov  0x10(%rbp),%rax` and `mov  %rdx,0x18(%rbp)` ).
2. Why is the return value stored in the 
   `mov  %rax,-0x8(%rbp)`

---

```
long absdiff(long x, long y)
{
    long result;
    if (x>y)
        result = x-y;
    else
        result = y-x;
    return result;
}
0x00000001004010e0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x00000001004010e1 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x00000001004010e4 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x00000001004010e8 <+8>:     mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
0x00000001004010ec <+12>:    mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
0x00000001004010f0 <+16>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x00000001004010f4 <+20>:    cmp    0x18(%rbp),%rax
0x00000001004010f8 <+24>:    jle    0x100401108 <absdiff+40>
0x00000001004010fa <+26>:    mov    0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x00000001004010fe <+30>:    sub    0x18(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000100401102 <+34>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100401106 <+38>:    jmp    0x100401114 <absdiff+52>
0x0000000100401108 <+40>:    mov    0x18(%rbp),%rax
0x000000010040110c <+44>:    sub    0x10(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000100401110 <+48>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
0x0000000100401114 <+52>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
0x0000000100401118 <+56>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
0x000000010040111c <+60>:    pop    %rbp
0x000000010040111d <+61>:    retq
```

Comment: _Why is it subtracting 10 bytes_..........`0x10=16`.....

Comment: You should start to identify how  `x` and  `y` are represented in the assembly code. Why do you expect 8 to be subtracted from the stack pointer? Hint: this is compiled as a 64 bit program.

Comment: I'd recommend compiling with optimizations enabled. The assembly will be *much* shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: @EOF much shorter: yes, easier to understand: not necessarily.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I find it essentially always more readable. This *may* however be rather specific to me.

Comment: @EOF well it probably depends on the assembly proficiency of the reader. Unoptimized code is more or less a "naive" one to one translation from C into assembly, whereas agressively optimized code may be very subtle and hard to understand.

Comment: Except that unoptimized code does a bunch of stupid, unintuitive stuff. I've never seen a single function (i.e., one that does a single task) that compiled into something unreadable when optimized. Instruction reordering can be confusing, but if the input function is manageably sized, this isn't really a barrier to understanding. We get *tons* of questions from people who don't understand unoptimized code, and very few questions from people who don't understand optimized code. Draw your own conclusions. Plus, unoptimized is not real-world, so if you're trying to *learn*, it's a waste of time.

Comment: @Olaf - I get it.  There are certain instructions that are not apparent as below - like why it is not offset with -0x10 instead of +0x10
mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) Why `sub $0x10, %rsp`?**

It is actually subtracting 16 bytes, in other words, its making space for the two 'long' arguments. try printing 'sizeof(long)' and I'm pretty sure you'll get '8' as the answer on the machine you're on.

**2) Why move register values to memory?**

Again this is where the computer is loading the two long values from the registers 'rcx' and 'rdx' into the memory space it made in '1)'. 0x10 and 0x18 have a difference of 8 bytes.

**3) Why is the return value stored in the `mov  %rax,-0x8(%rbp)`?**

It's stored temporarily because before leaving the function, the %rax register is used for some other computations. Therefore if it was not saved it would have been over written, and you can see that after those computations are done the value is again loaded into rax.

```
mov%rax,-0x8(%rbp) <--- saving
jmp    0x100401114 <absdiff+52>
...
mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
-0x8(%rbp),%rax" < -- retrieving
```

**A Suggestion**

I'm pretty sure you'll find this link really helpful:

https://www.recurse.com/blog/7-understanding-c-by-learning-assembly

Comment: Please make an effort and format your answer correctly. Then you'll get an upvote from me.

Comment: There! Thank you for the rant, it really was useful. Peace! (y)

Comment: is this not overwriting anything that is already present in the memory location when it does (rbp) - 8? Or that location is already allocated to the function?
mov  %rax,-0x8(%rbp)

Comment: For #2, you are explaining *what* it is doing, but not actually answering *why*. The why is because this is unoptimized code, and every intermediate result gets spilled to memory, instead of being kept in registers. Same thing for #3: there is absolutely no reason to store and reload `RAX`. This is just busy work done by unoptimized code to facilitate source-code-level debugging.

Comment: also since stack goes from higher to lower address, adding 16/24 bytes to base pointer takes you to higher address - that is above the base pointer? I expected it to be mov %rcx, -0x10(%rbp) instead of mov %rcx, 0x10(%rbp)
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is relative to the *base* pointer here (`RBP`), not the stack pointer (`RSP`). Look at the prologue code (first 3 instructions), and you'll see what happens to `RBP` and `RSP`. Yet another way that you can be confused by looking at unoptimized code, if you don't understand how stack pointers work. Compare to the [optimized code produced by GCC](https://gcc.godbolt.org/g/Cx9qzp). @user

Comment: @CodyGray the optimized code is much cleaner and easier. But my original question was, the below two instructions offset 16 and 32 bytes from the rbp location (base of the frame). When we "add" this offset, does not it increase the address and goes to "top" of the stack - whereas when we allocated address we "subtracted" from the rsp. 
mov    %rcx,0x10(%rbp)
mov    %rdx,0x18(%rbp)
Are we writing to the same location that we created?
sub    $0x10,%rsp

Comment: Yes, because the offset is relative to `RBP`, not `RSP`. That's why I told you to look at the first couple of instructions, to see how those two registers get set. Notice that `RBP` is initialized to the *original* value of `RSP`, *before* `RSP` gets decremented. You might find [this diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687662/why-does-rbp-point-to-nothing/44693674#44693674) helpful. @user